# Import Unsubscribed emails from another source

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, import

Is there a way to mark an entire data extension as unsubscribed?

Here's my order of operation:

- Created a data extension [SGMG]
- imported a list of emails from our operational email service
- Joined our [Users] DE to [SGMG]

In essence, that will be a suppression DE.  However, all those subscribers are technically still subscribed (which isn't ideal, in my opinion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change their status in the all subscribers list. This is a convoluted process.

Follow these steps:

1. A query activity to put them in a DE (with status unsubscribed)
2. A data extract activity of that Data Extension
3. A file transfer activity to move the extract to the export ftp destination
4. Another file transfer activity to move the extract to the import ftp location (you could also do this your computer using an FTP client, but I am guessing you want to automate it).
5. This into the AllSubscribersList

You also have the option of unsubscribing them using a [Script Activity](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/subscriber_server_side_javascript_functions/unsubscribe/)
This way they will be unsubscribed and you would not need that suppression list

Comment: That is convoluted...But thanks!  I'll get after it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and came across this post, but kept digging and somebody on the partner community shared this with me:

[**Update Subscriber Status in Marketing Cloud**](https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_subscriber_status.htm&type=5)

This solution is pretty simple and worked perfectly for my use case. I just exported the DE, updated the CSV, and imported it to All Subscribers. Easy peasy.